# Django variable not visible in header section

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I have a basic start to a blog, it lists out blog articles from the database in post_list.html that extends from header.html. I am trying also to get a variable in the header as a slogan but this is not working.

header.html - this renders without the "propaganda.slogan" which is entered from the admin pages and has content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>hey!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/bulma.css' %}"      type="text/css"/> 
  </head>    
  <body>
    <section class="hero is-success is-bold">
        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
                {% block slogan %}
                    <ul>
                    {% for propaganda in propagandas %}
                        <li>{{ propaganda.slogan }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>       
                {% endblock %}
                <h1 class="title">
                    My weblog
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

post_list.html extends header.html and displays a list of posts from models.py:

```
{% extends "blog/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <section class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="title"><a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                <p>{{ post.summary|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                <p>published: {{ post.last_edited }}</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    {% endfor %}    
{% endblock %}
```

models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Propaganda(models.Model):
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slogan


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False, null=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_edited = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

finally, views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Propaganda

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def header(request):
    propagandas = Propaganda.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/header.html', {'propagandas': propagandas})
```

So why can I get the list of post titles, summary and date in the post_list.html but I can't get a list of propagandist slogans in the header?

to me it looks like the same code, almost?

I  get no error from the dev server or in the browser :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass the list of propagnadas to the context of the current template; including a template has little or nothing to do with the *associated* (if this makes any sense in the first place) view of the included template:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    propagandas = Propaganda.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts, 'propagandas': propagandas})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, can you explain to me why the current template is "post_list" when I am getting the variable value in the header "header.html"? I would have thought that the template was the header template. Seems like I have a view for post_list that is initiated after and below the header, but then I add the slogans to that and they appear in the header! Doesn't make sense to me, although you caught the error quickly. Seems like I am building a view that is one file, and creating a single view in views.py allows me to get the object in the header?

Comment: [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include): *Loads a template and renders it with the **current context**.* The current context is supplied by the `post_list` view which before now, does not supply a list of propagandas. Don't think about the included template as having a separate view.